# Possible to convert accelerometer $x,y,z$ measurements into quaternion?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, complex-numbers

I have an inertial measurement unit (IMU) with an accelerometer that reports the acceleration (a) along the $x$, $y$ and $z$-axis in milli-$g$. I can get the Euler angles for roll ($\phi$) and pitch ($\theta$) as follows:

$$
 {\phi= \;{\arctan}\;{{{{\rm a}_y}} \over {\sqrt {{\rm a}_x^2 + {\rm a}_z^2} }}}
$$

$$
{\theta} = \;{\arctan\;{{{{\rm a}_x}} \over {\sqrt {{\rm a}_y^2 + {\rm a}_z^2} }}}  
$$

I could then convert these values from their Euler representation to quaternions. For example, for the roll I could do this:

$$
    q_{r}=\cos{\phi\over 2}\begin{bmatrix}{ 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0}\end{bmatrix}+\sin{\phi\over 2}\begin{bmatrix}{ 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0}\end{bmatrix}.
    \label{qr}
$$

But I'd prefer to avoid using Euler angles at all since they are susceptible to gimbal lock. Is it possible to somehow get the quaternions directly from the accelerometer's $a_x$, $a_y$ and $a_z$ values? I am very new at this and only recently learned some of these concepts and can't really find any clear literature that doesn't need an advanced math/physics degree to understand.

Comment: doesn't [wiki page][1] helps?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_Angles_to_Quaternion_Conversion

Comment: No, as that is using Euler angles by obtaining them from doing trigonometry on the accelerometer's vectors and converting them to quaternions. I was asking if it is possible to use the accelerometer's vectors to convert to quaternions directly without involving Euler angles.